# Why does this .NET class not accept this other parent class as a type parameter via inheritance?

Tags: .net, generics, inheritance, covariance, contravariance

I'm trying to figure out why the compiler is complaining about this (what I thought was a simple) inheritance scenario:

Given this abstract class..

```
public class AbstractAnimalValidator<TAnimal> : AbstractValidator<TAnimal> 
    where TAnimal: Animal<IFoo, IBar>, new()
{
}
```

I then try to create this concrete class...

`public class CatValidator : AbstractAnimalValidator<Cat>{ }`

I get this error...

[image]

Ok, so what's a `Cat`?

```
public abstract class Animal<TFoo, TBar>
    where TFoo : IFoo
    where TBar : IBar { }

public class Cat : Animal<RedFoo, CleanBar> { }
```

I just don't get it :/ the Cat is of those two types ......

Now [this is the FULL REPO on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/71Ql4t) to show a live example of this.

#### Update 1:

I guess i'm *also* asking for is
1. *why* doesn't my code work? Ie. My brain says that should work, but the compiler says: `given this scenario XXX .. I wouldn't know what to do ...`
2. How to fix this up, so i can learn.

basically, i've read the covariance/contravariance stuff a number of times and my head keeps assploding ... especially with some crap foo/bar examples. Hopefully, with my *a-little-bit-more-concrete* example, I might just be able to grok this a wee bit more.

Comment: Classes are invariant so `Cat` is not an `Animal<IFoo, IBar>`.

Comment: You need to understand covariance and contravariance, a concept that was introduced to .NET in version 4. Look at interface IEnumerable<out T> as an example of covariance (the out keyword) and for Action<in T> for contravariance.

Comment: How is using generics "simple inheritance scenario"?

Comment: @lee how is `Cat` not an `Animal<IFoo, IBar>` ?? the declaration of my `Cat` is `Cat : Animal<RedFoo, CleanBar>` and `RedFoo` is an `IFoo` and `CleanBar` is an `IBar`. I just don't get it :( Also .. i've got both getters and setters for each property, so I can't use `in` or `out` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Cat` is a subclass of `Animal<RedFoo, CleanBar>`, `AbstractAnimalValidator` expects something that is a subtype of `Animal<IFoo, IBar>` but `Animal<RedFoo, CleanBar>` is *not* a subtype of `Animal<IFoo, IBar>` and thus `Cat` is also not a subtype.

*Please note that in this terminology subtype is a more general term then subclass. `B` is a subclass of `A` if `B` inherits `A`, and `B` is a subtype of `A` if a `B` type object can be assigned to an `A` type variable.*

To fix this make the `TFoo` and `TBar` type parameters *Covariant*. This is only allowed for interfaces in C#, so you need to introduce a new interface:

```
public interface IAnimal<out TFoo, out TBar>
  where TFoo : IFoo
  where TBar : IBar { }
```

And use it like this:

```
public class AbstractAnimalValidator<TAnimal>
where TAnimal : IAnimal<IFoo, IBar>, new()
{
}

public abstract class Animal<TFoo, TBar> : IAnimal<TFoo, TBar>
  where TFoo : IFoo
  where TBar : IBar { }
```

This way `Cat` becomes a subtype of `IAnimal<IFoo, IBar>`, because `RedFoo` is a subclass of `IFoo` and `CleanBar`is a subclass of `IBar`.